# Using Jquery AJAX to get object from ASP.NET web server

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services, post

I'm trying to call an asp.net web service using Jquery Ajax post method like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: this._baseURL + method,
    data: data,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: fnSuccess,
    error: fnError
});
```

On the server side I have web method that looks like

```
public myClass myWebMethod(Guid Id) { ... }
```

The problem is I get an error in return saying "500 internal server error" and

> Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: \u0027Id\u0027.

I've tried this for data :

`'{"Id":"thisistheid"}'` and `'{ Id:thisistheid}'`

...and many other combinations that I found in examples.

Does any body know how to handle this please?

Comment: You may fire up Fiddler and see what HTTP request is  being passed by your Jquery. For me, this often will lead to a solution.

Answer (score 1):

just try with

```
data : {Id :"thisistheid"}
```

without quotes around the object

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Fabrizio that was part of the answer! I finally figured it out:

```
data = {Id :"thisistheid"};
...
$.ajax({
...
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
...
});
```

Works like a charm.